# Permanently Deleted Chrome Bookmarks Recovery? or AppData full Recovery? Any Level of Solution Available in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bookmarks, file-recovery, temporary-internet-files

Win 7, I deleted during disk clean up and manually from AppData all files, which includes Chrome bookmarks as well! I tried to restore system to recover chrome bookmarks, but they are not showing up any more...

Is there any way possible to get those deleted chrome bookmarks back, even if it is by any files/data recovery software? is there any way of getting Appdata restored back to its previous state with all temp and data files back?

I noticed after system restore, my recycle bin was showing weird name files, i restored all of them and several time it asked me to merge or copy / replace with existing files, I have only one system restore back for previous date, if it can be helpful, I would like to know the steps to make it useful and effective to get chrome bookmarks back anyway possible...

Thanks for your consideration...

Comment: Hi Rsya, thanks for participating, I haven't connected it, please check my comment made for Bob below, thanks and looking forward to really have a firm answer about this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, I'd recommend that you make an image of the drive so you can always go back if recovery doesn't work.

See [here.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/i-have-deleted-the-appdata-folder-accidentally-as/949642a9-8aab-4c6a-8c03-c2add2ae20e3)

**Method 1:**

1. Manually recreate the deleted folder.
2. Right-click it.
3. Left-click "Restore previous version".
4. Follow the prompts.

**Method 2:**

If **System Restore** is operative on your machine and if you have a suitable System Restore point then you can load it as a VHD (Virtual Hard Disk) using [System Restore Explorer](http://nicbedford.co.uk/software/systemrestoreexplorer/).

[image]

When you select a restore point and mount it the tool will create a shortcut to that particular restore point which will allow you to browse the contents and copy files.

[image]

Once you have finished with a particular restore point you can either use the tool to unmount it or simply delete the shortcut (deleting the shortcut will not delete the restore point).

**Method 3**

\Download [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) and search for the keywords in the file - since you know its format then search for .bak extensions only. This will take a while so do this if the other methods don't work, and make sure you already have an image of the drive!

\

**Conclusion?**

Always keep backups.

Comment: Thanks Rsya Solutions! I highly appreciate this guideline, It will take some time, I will try these options for sure and will let you know... About the image of the drive, is there a possibility of system crash during the testing of 2nd and 3rd method? for which I should have an image of the drive? just confirming...

Comment: Possibility of system crashing is minimal. The reason I recommend that you do the image is because the longer you leave it, the higher chance that the deleted file will be overwrited - then the file can never be recovered. Windows 7 has a built in system image tool (or you could use a 3rd party one).

Comment: 1st Method, didn't worked... I am trying 2nd Method at the moment... When I first mounted a restore point, it shows me some files, which I copied then I Unmounted it and now trying again to Unmount last important restore point, where I will have those bak files stored, but now it is opening SRE but when I click mount it is doing nothing and not opening any popup window with mounted files or not even creating a shortcut, like it did first time! I restart system but it is not mounting anything after clicked! Have you experience something similar? thanks for swift response..

Comment: 2nd Method works Rsya, thanks a lot, please check my detailed explanation at bottom... I am hoping lots of people will get benefit from this forum and your presented solutions... Thanks once again...

Answer (score 0):

Open your Gmail click the three line option icon and sign into chrome. If you set this up, it will have your bookmarks in it.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I haven't associated my google account with Chrome...

Is it possible to recover bookmark file by any other way... Once bookmarks are saved in this .bak file type, they are on pc anyway... So just like through 3rd party different recovery software, media and different extensions files can be recovered from hard drive, then why can not a simple Bookmark file!? 

Kindly confirm, is it really impossible to recover bookmark extension or file with any third party recovery software? or by system restore? 

Thanks for your swift response...

Comment: OK. Have you associated it with another device (cell phone or tablet?)   If so, you can add another device (your computer) and get your bookmarks.  If not, read here: http://www.howtogeek.com/111784/how-to-recover-accidentally-deleted-bookmarks-in-chrome-firefox/  Also it is easy to backup your bookmarks using Chrome's bookmark manager export function. G'luck!

Comment: Also, I have used undelete programs, like Rsya mentioned, with some success.  It is important to use them before those disc areas are over-written by other data. G'luck!

Comment: Thanks Bob, I am trying Rsya 2nd proposed method, just stuck at one point, but still I believe this will helps everyone who might be facing similar situation... Thanks for follow-up...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bob for starting the discussion and Thanks a lot to Rsya Studios who ended it up with great useful methods. I thanks both of you for your instant responses, which solved this Chrome Bookmarks Recovery problem. I had noticed on different forums that lots of people are still figuring out the way to recover their lost Chrome Bookmarks and now I am sure that after reading Rsya methods they will have a hope of efficiently recovering it with ease...

**2nd Method works the best for Recovering Chrome Bookmarks,** if they are manually deleted permanently from AppData or while running Disk Cleanup or may be mistakenly through Chrome settings...

Here is my observation, you must have an Active System Restore Point and ofcourse (SRE) to Mount/Check files of previous Restore Points (before actually running System Restore / however you wont be needing Full System Restore after you copy required internal files through this SRE Software) and manually reach the "Bookmarks" or "Bookmarks.bak" file inside "Google" folder...

This is the destination: C:\Users(Your User Name)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Now I used two ways; I copy the "Bookmarks" and "Bookmarks.bak" from the final destination and paste it on desktop, then I also (to be on safe side) copy the entire "Google" folder and paste it on desktop...

Now, Unmount (Clicked on Unmount) that particular System Restore Point (Which is open inside SRE Software) and then go back to your destination folder and paste/replace first those desktop copied "Bookmarks" and "Bookmarks.bak" files... Check your Chrome Browser you will have Bookmarks back!!!...

What I did, is just that after updating Bookmarks files, I also replace the entire "Google" folder and this bring back some of previous Chrome settings and recently viewed body tabs as well!!!

It might look like that a Full System Restore can also bring these lost Bookmarks back, but I tried that and it didn't worked for me. If it works fine for you then that is ok, however in the presence of (SRE) software it is a bad choice...

Thank you once again Rsya Studios for your solutions and kind support, highly appreciated it... All the best everyone!!!

Comment: Welcome, glad that you got the file back :)